# Difference not detected with GIT for Windows but GIT/MSYS2 detect it

Tags: git, dfm

I have a text file called `Main.dfm`. In some cases only a single letter is changed in the file.

Comparing the same file in the same directory with git for windows and git/msys2 gives different results.

(Upper Window: Git for Windows detects no change. Lower Window: Git und msys2 detects the changement)

[image: Compare of 2 outputs]

What can be the reasons, that this changement is detected only with the git/msys2?

(I've checked the settings of the 2 git installation with `git config --list`, but haven't seen any relevant differences)

Comment: Differences when checking `git config --global -l`?

Comment: Can you see other differences in the Git for Windows client?

Comment: Did you add the file in Git for Windows? If so, `git diff --cached $path` is needed to show the diff.

Comment: Good point (but they seem to be the same repository). Still, the output of `git status` would be helpful (as _text_, see [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551))

Comment: You really need to give the Git config as per the first comment. Otherwise no one can even start to think about this. A hunch I had when reading this is that you have Git for Windows installed with its `fsmonitor` feature and it caches/cached the status of the file and assumes it not to have changed based on _something_ (e.g. timestamp?!), whereas the other Git instance may not rely on that. What you are missing is that Git for Windows really has a number of Windows-specific patches, whereas the other one doesn't. Also, do you use MSYS or MSYS2? Is `/C/DATA` on NTFS?

Comment: Your version of Git for Windows is also quite old, perhaps you'll want to run `winget upgrade -e --id Git.Git` to upgrade it to the latest version?! The question about NTFS above concerns the timestamp resolution which is different on different OSs. Since `/C/DATA` (or the relevant subfolder) could well be a junction or volume mount point to another drive, this is a relevant question here.